# Creating Bulk Users in AD With CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I am working on a Power Shell script that will create bulk users in Active Directory. As stated in a previous post, I'm fairly new to Power Shell and want to be safe before I go live with anything. Below is the script, some of it borrowed. It will be reading data from the .csv noted in the Import-CSV cmdlet. Ideally, this would create the user and define the user's full name, first name, last name, username, SAM name, e-mail, title, description and manager. It would also set a password.

I would love any feedback on how the below script looks. Please let me know if you have any questions or need any additional information.

```
    Import-Module activedirectory

$ADUsers = Import-CSV C:\scripts\hourlyimport.csv

foreach ($User in $ADUsers)
{
    #read user data from each field in each row and assign the data to a variable as below

    $Username   = $User.username
    $Firstname  = $User.firstname
    $Lastname   = $User.lastname
    $Password   = $User.password
    $OU         = $User.ou
    $Title      = $User.title
    $Manager    = $User.manager

    #check to see if the user already exists in AD

    if (Get-ADUser -F {SamAccountName -eq $Username})
    {
         #if user does exist, give a warning

         Write-Warning "A user account with username $Username already exist in Active Directory. Say wha?!?"
    }
    else
    {
        #if user does not exist then proceed to create the new user account

        #account will be created in the OU provided by the $OU variable read from the CSV file

        New-ADUser `
            -SamAccountName $Username `
            -UserPrincipalName "$Username@thredup.com" `
        -Email "$Username@thredup.com" `
            -Name "$Firstname $Lastname" `
            -GivenName $Firstname `
            -Surname $Lastname `
            -Enabled $True `
            -DisplayName "$Lastname, $Firstname" `
            -Path $OU `
        -Description "$Title" `
        -Title "$Title" `
        -Manager "$Manager" `
            -AccountPassword (convertto-securestring $Password -AsPlainText -Force)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks pretty good to me. You are somewhat inconsistent with the use of `"`, for example you don't need to write `-Title "$Title"`, you can leave away the `"` in this case.

You could probably do some fancy optimization with [splatting](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2010/10/18/use-splatting-to-simplify-your-powershell-scripts/) here, reducing the assignments, but since it is a quite unknown feature among many readers I wouldn't go for it here.

One thing I'm missing is error handling. With the default settings, your script will print out errors when something goes wrong, but continue the loop. Is this intended? It is often good practice to state your intention explicitly by setting `$ErrorActionPreference` at the start of your script.

Comment: Got it. So I only need quotations when combining data, like adding the @domain.com or creating a "full" name?

Comment: Yes, Using `"` with variables is the PowerShell method of using `string.Format`